# Call static method in constructor — CoffeeScript

Tags: class, static, coffeescript

Say I'm declaring a class `Game`.

```
class @Game
    constructor: ->
        @id = Game.generateNewGameId() # <---
    player1: null
    player2: null
    @generateNewGameId: -> "blahblah23"
```

Here, I'm using `generateNewGameId` as `Game.generateNewGameId()`.

Is this the right way or is there a better way? I've tried using `this::generateNewGameId()` but the scope's different.

Comment: Uh, have you tried `@id = @generateNewGameId()`?

Comment: @MariusKjeldahl `@generateNewGameId()` is a static method. What you mentioned would work if it was an instance method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really want `generateNewGameId` to be a class method then you can use [`@constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to get at it:

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself [...]

So something like this:

```
class Game
    constructor: ->
        @id = @constructor.generateNewGameId()
    @generateNewGameId: ->
        "blahblah23"
```

Note that this will do The Right Thing if you subclass `Game`:

```
class C extends Game # With an override of the class method
    @generateNewGameId: ->
        'pancakes'    

class C2 extends Game # or without
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Vz2SE/

Comment: It's worth looking at @epidemian's answer. That might be what most people are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think the way you are accessing it is OK. You can also do `@constructor.generateNewGameId()` if you don't want to write `Game.generateNewGameId()` for some reason, but i'd prefer the later. Update: as [@mu is too short mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569537/581845), the `@constructor` allows you to get the constructor of the instance, which can be differ from `Game` (in a subclass) so it has greater flexibility; if that flexibility is required in this case, definitely go for that :)

If the `generateNewGameId` function will not be accessed from outside the `Game` class, you can use a private function instead of a class method:

```
class @Game
  gameIdCounter = 0
  generateNewGameId = -> gameIdCounter++
  constructor: ->
    @id = generateNewGameId()
  player1: null
  player2: null

console.log (new Game).id # -> 0
console.log (new Game).id # -> 1
```

[Example at coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20%40Game%0A%20%20gameIdCounter%20%3D%200%0A%20%20generateNewGameId%20%3D%20-%3E%20gameIdCounter%2B%2B%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40id%20%3D%20generateNewGameId%28%29%0A%20%20player1%3A%20null%0A%20%20player2%3A%20null%0A%0Aconsole.log%20%28new%20Game%29.id%20%23%20-%3E%200%0Aconsole.log%20%28new%20Game%29.id%20%23%20-%3E%201).

There both `gameIdCounter` and `generateNewGameId` are private variables inside the `Game` class.